# Remove the domain name from URLs

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to remove the domain name from URLs with different schemes. 
examples of url:

```
http://www.example.org/cat1/page1
example.org/cat1/page1
https://www.example.org/cat1/page1
```

outcome:

```
cat1/page1
```

It can be done both on django template or on the views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.example.org/cat1/page1')
>>> o.path
'/cat1/page1'
```

Note, that `example.org/cat1/page1` is a valid path, so you can't remove the domain from it.  As workaround you can manually add the protocol to the url string:

```
>>> url  = 'example.org/cat1/page1'
>>> if not '//' in url:
...     url = 'http://' + url
... 
>>> o = urlparse(url)
>>> o.path
'/cat1/page1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The request object has this information also:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#module-django.http

HttpRequest.path
A string representing the full path to the requested page, not including the domain.

Example: "/music/bands/the_beatles/"

This will let you get the path of the current page, so it might not work in your situation